# Flutter InAppWebView inside SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-inappwebview

I have a request to make a card containing a web view followed by more widgets. The view should look something like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1selaEscp7XUADpnYEsyZdbyF6iEqh4a3/view?usp=sharing).

I have made implementation like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  ...
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        ...
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: _webviewHeightSetInOnLoadStop
              child: InAppWebview(
                ...
              )
            ),
            ...
          )
      ),
      Widget1(),
      Widget2(),
      Widget3(),
    ]
```

Where the `_webviewHeightSetInOnLoadStop` is set like this:

```
  onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
    final height = await controller.evaluateJavascript(
      source: "document.documentElement.scrollHeight;",
    );
    ...
    setState(() {
      _webviewHeightSetInOnLoadStop = height;
      ...
    });
  }
```

The problem with this implementation is that when the webview is too large the Android crashes with:

```
IllegalStateException: Unable to create a layer for InAppWebView, size 960x39192 exceeds max size 16384
```

in my understanding, this is thrown due to the height of the webview, which is system restricted.

So I desire a behavior in which webview is scrollable, its container has a fixed height that is a little bit bigger than the screen (when needed) and when the end of the scroll of the webview is reached in either direction the drag event is passed to the `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: can you add _webviewHeightSetInOnLoadStop value

Comment: @SalihCan Added the onLoadStop method where _webviewHeightSetInOnLoadStop is set.

Comment: Is _webviewHeightSetInOnLoadStop give you 39192?

Answer (score 0):

There is another plugin which can do what you are looking for exactly

```
webview_flutter_plus: ^0.2.3
```

Try this code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:webview_flutter_plus/webview_flutter_plus.dart';

class ImageEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageEditor({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageEditorState createState() => _ImageEditorState();
}

class _ImageEditorState extends State<ImageEditor> {
  WebViewPlusController? _controller;
  double _height = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: _height,
                child: WebViewPlus(
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                    this._controller = controller;      controller.loadUrl('https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus');
              },
              onPageFinished: (url) {

                _controller!.getHeight().then((double height) {
                  print("Height:  " + height.toString());
                  setState(() {
                    _height = height;
                  });
                });
              },
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height:200,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            height:200,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Container(
            height:200,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.green,
            ),
           ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem with the crashing Webview on older Android devices (Android 8 for example). I probably need a solution for handling the touch events from SingleChildScrollView when the end of the scroll of the Webview is reached.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check

Comment: I've tried it and the Webview is still crashing. In that example, the developer is doing the exact same thing - gets the web view height using javascript and sets it as sized box height. The crash is caused by the large height of the content of the Webview. That's why I need a solution with gestures handled both by the SingleChildScrollView and Webview when needed.

Comment: if you dont mind can you send post the url of the web page

Comment: Could be any web page with long enough content.

Comment: I tried a long web page it worked fine on my phone. Can you provide any long webpage please? I shall try with the one that you send me

Answer (score -1):

i think you should implement a custom size or just limiting it for the intended behaviour for the container of your webview and make that responsive so the screen doesn't get any crashes or like that in older devices.

Answer (score -1):

You should try flutter_html instead web view

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Until they dont release the version 3 or above, `flutter_html` is almost useless.